# Generating offset line from MultiLineString in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, qgis-processing, linestring, offset

I have a MULTILINESTRING in my CSV file, and I want to generate a copy of it offset to the right by a few meters. I've run *Single Sided Buffer*, and *Offset Lines*, and neither of them seem to generate the correct geometry.

Do I need to convert this string to some other geometry or file type, or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the ["Translate"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#translate) tool in the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) (under `Vector Geometry`).

Set the x-axis to whatever distance you want to create the copy:

[image]

Output similar to the following:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this worked, however, it seems that WSG 84 limits me to degrees translation. How would I need to translate this to what CRS to do offset in meters?

Comment: Reproject your data to a projected CRS eg UTM. Search for "UTM zone" in the CRS list and find the appropriate UTM zone for your area (mine is UTM zone 56S (EPSG:32756)